Push notification interaction does not open app, rather opens a transparent window with "Notification Message" title
I am using multiple push sdks in my project. I have SF Auth SDK as well.
I have configured SFMC properly and I can receive the notifications as well as the inbox messages, but when I interact with the push notification from notification tray I don't see the app opening rather a transparent background window opens and all I can see if the title "Notification Message"
my code
SFMCSdk.configure(
                applicationContext as Application,
                SFMCSdkModuleConfig.build {
                    pushModuleConfig = MarketingCloudConfig.builder().apply {
                        setApplicationId(BuildConfig.SALESFORCE_MC_APP_ID)
                        setAccessToken("########")
                        setMarketingCloudServerUrl(BuildConfig.SALESFORCE_MC_SERVER_URL)
                        setMid(BuildConfig.SALESFORCE_MC_MID)
                        setNotificationCustomizationOptions(
                            NotificationCustomizationOptions.create(R.drawable.ic_stat_app_logo_transparent)
                        )
                        setMarkMessageReadOnInboxNotificationOpen(true)
                        setDelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet(true)
                        setInboxEnabled(true) // Enable Inbox messaging
                    }.build(applicationContext)
                }
            ) { initStatus ->
                when (initStatus.status) {
                    com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.InitializationStatus.SUCCESS -> {
                        logVerbose("SFMC STATUS", "Marketing Cloud init was successful")
                        SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
                            sdk.mp {
                                try {
                                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                            SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
                                                sdk.mp {
                                                    logDebug(
                                                        "FIREBASE_MESSAGING",
                                                        "SUCCESS: task result: ${task.result}"
                                                    )
                                                    it.pushMessageManager.setPushToken(task.result)
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                } catch (e: ExceptionInInitializerError) {
                                    logError(
                                        "FIREBASE_MESSAGING",
                                        "FAILURE: Exception in initializer. ${e.message}"
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.InitializationStatus.FAILURE -> {
                        logError("SFMC STATUS", "Marketing Cloud failed to initialize.")
                    }
                }

I have tried other options as well, for example handling the channel, composition and pendingIntent through app as well but same behaviour
  fun createNotificationChannel(context: Context) {
        val channelId = "default_channel_id"
        val channelName = "Default Channel"
        val channelDescription = "This is the default notification channel"
        val importance = android.app.NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance).apply {
            description = channelDescription
        }

        val notificationManager: android.app.NotificationManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as android.app.NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

...
      SFMCSdk.configure(
                applicationContext as Application,
                SFMCSdkModuleConfig.build {
                    pushModuleConfig = MarketingCloudConfig.builder().apply {
                        setApplicationId(BuildConfig.SALESFORCE_MC_APP_ID)
                        setAccessToken(it)
                        setMarketingCloudServerUrl(BuildConfig.SALESFORCE_MC_SERVER_URL)
                        setMid(BuildConfig.SALESFORCE_MC_MID)
                        setMarkMessageReadOnInboxNotificationOpen(true)
                        setDelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet(true)
                        setInboxEnabled(true) // Enable Inbox messaging
                        setUrlHandler(this@ABCApplication)
                        setNotificationCustomizationOptions(
                            NotificationCustomizationOptions.create { context, notificationMessage ->
                                // Ensure the notification channel is created
                                createNotificationChannel(context)
                                val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "default_channel_id")
                                builder.setContentTitle(notificationMessage.title)
                                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_app_logo_transparent)
                                builder.setContentText(notificationMessage.alert)
                                builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                                builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                                builder.setContentIntent(
                                    NotificationManager.redirectIntentForAnalytics(
                                        context,
                                        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                            context,
                                            Random().nextInt(),
                                            Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java),
                                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                                        ),
                                        notificationMessage,
                                        true
                                    )
                                )

                                val notificationManager =
                                    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as android.app.NotificationManager
                                notificationManager.notify(Random().nextInt(), builder.build())
                                Log.d(
                                    "Notification",
                                    "Notification built and displayed successfully."
                                )
                                builder
                            }
                        )
                    }.build(applicationContext)
                }
            ) { initStatus ->
                when (initStatus.status) {
                    com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.InitializationStatus.SUCCESS -> {
                        logVerbose("SFMC STATUS", "Marketing Cloud init was successful")
                        SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
                            sdk.mp {
                                try {
                                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                            SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
                                                sdk.mp {
                                                    logDebug(
                                                        "FIREBASE_MESSAGING",
                                                        "SUCCESS: task result: ${task.result}"
                                                    )
                                                    it.pushMessageManager.setPushToken(task.result)
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                } catch (e: ExceptionInInitializerError) {
                                    logError(
                                        "FIREBASE_MESSAGING",
                                        "FAILURE: Exception in initializer. ${e.message}"
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.InitializationStatus.FAILURE -> {
                        logError("SFMC STATUS", "Marketing Cloud failed to initialize.")
                    }
                }
            }

and
  override fun handleUrl(context: Context, p1: String, p2: String): PendingIntent? {
        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
            data = Uri.parse(p1)
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            1,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )
    }

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Open a support case.

So, open a support case, BUT you're calling notify in your own code AND handing the builder back to the SDK. You have an implementation problem in this code.

@BilMote yes that I fixed. Now I am getting the notifications as I wanted, will open a case soon. Thanks.

No need for a case if you resolved it :)

Looks like you're calling notify from your own code. If you want to do that then you should return null to the SDK. Otherwise, remove the call to notify and let the SDK do it's work with the intent you provided.
